# Handle when drawing of polygons is complete in google maps api v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, dom, google-maps-api-3, rendering

It seems that drawing of polygons is asynchronous in [google maps api v3](http://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference). Try to click the "Load" button in this example:

http://jsfiddle.net/rmXXF/

the text "DONE" is written much sooner than the grid is drawn! It seems that drawing of rectangle grid is asynchronous. **I want the text DONE displayed AFTER the grid is drawn!** Is there some event handler for this?

The important part of code is in function `action()`:

```
polygons = draw_all_squares(map); // draw grid here
document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'DONE'; // displayed 2 seconds
                                                      // before the grid!
```

Note that map 'idle' event doesn't work for this, because the map is not moving/zooming. You can try here: 
http://jsfiddle.net/92Hxj/

Maybe it has something to do not with google maps but with browser rendering? In any case, some event handler for this should be present.

Comment: Unfortunately there is not. What is the use case?

Comment: @broady, the use case is almost exactly what you see in the example, but the squares are loaded with ajax. I'm setting the status indicator to "LOADING..." before ajax request, and set it back to "DONE" after I get the data and render them... but it doesn't work - the status indicator says "DONE" and user stares few seconds at an empty map.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By triggering a small recentering of the map after drawing all the polygons this is added to the same internal google maps event queue as can be seen in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/rmXXF/40/

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function() {
 document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'DONE';
});
```

and

```
my_map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(my_map.getCenter().lat(), my_map.getCenter().lng() + .000000001));
```

Comment: Very nice, David. I'd make one change - use addListenerOnce

Comment: This was an amazing hack. Thanks once again :-)

Answer (score 3):

You should use an overlay and listen to the drawing manager's 'rectanglecomplete' event. I can code up an example after lunch.

David is right. I misread the documentation. Apologize. He should get the bounty.

Comment: Wow, looks exactly like the thing I was looking for. An example would be great!

Comment: The bounty needs to be rewarded soon... you stand a chance, if your answer is complete. :-)

Comment: Ok, I might be mistaken, but the drawing manager is a part of the library meant for user-end editing and the '*'-complete events in this context are meant for when the *user* finished drawing something, not when the 'native' google.maps.Rectangle is drawn (as it won't trigger in that situation as far as I know), so why is this incomplete and as far as I know even incorrect answer getting so many upvotes? And even if you were to be able to fake such an user action that would speed wise still give an unacceptable overhead.

Comment: David is right. I misread the documentation. Apologize. He should get the bounty.

Comment: @DavidMulder, [you are right!](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DrawingManager) I guess it took so many upvotes because it sounded as a real solution to the problem :-) At least good that I strictly required the example (I just wondered why it's still not coming :-)). I retracted my upvote :)