# Loading kml markers above polygon

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am working with a google map api 3, on my map i want to generate kml markers after polygons, but it is not working, my markers are generate before polygons so i am not able to click marker.

Comment: How are you generating the polygons?  Are they native Google Maps Javascript API v3 Polygons? Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I am generating polygons using:
var polygon_marker = new google.maps.Polygon

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Maps API V3 - KML Layer vs. JS created Polygons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13054735/google-maps-api-v3-kml-layer-vs-js-created-polygons)

Answer (score 0):

Native Google Maps Javascript API v3 polygons will *always* appear on top of KML layers.  If you want to control the order, use a KmlLayer to display the polygon as well, add that layer first or control the order with the zIndex property of the KmlLayers.

related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35455830/kml-ordering-in-google-maps-api (including example)

Comment: My polygons are drawing by coordinates which are saved in database. And on click of polygon info window opens. How can i draw polygon using this effects with kml layers logic any example.