# Which technology to use with Google maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to develop a map application with about 500 or so polygons and some data associated with each polygon. The data for each polygon, to give an approximation, would be about 100 string fields of moderate length (say each under 50 characters). I expect this data (but not the polygons) to change arbitrarily every 10 minutes or so.

There seems to be a number of technologies to build this -- fusion table, the "raw" map api with a sql database to hold the data, map engine etc. I was wondering which of these various options is appropriate (and why) for the amount of data and level of churn I have mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I think for your case the raw map API is very appropriate. 500 polygons is a low number, map server would certainly be an overkill. For fusion tables I would go if I had thousands of markers, but not for 500. I am now using roughly this number of polygons in the raw API without problems.

PS: For drawing polygons with raw API there is a trick that took me long time to research, might come in handy later for you: [Handle when drawing of polygons is complete in google maps api v3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9850444/684229)

Comment: Thanks Tomas. Can you expand on the reason for you choices? Is fusion table a good solution, but simply an overkill? Since fusion table seems to allow a simpler API, I am tempted to go that way, but I have vaguely heard that it has problems with updates.

Comment: @Pradipta honestly don't know, I never used Fusion tables. I only now it is rendered server side, which is efficient if you have many data points... but you have to probably store the data at google (?). But with this quite little amount of data I would really go with the standard API, it was my way and seems easiest to me. But it is certainly not the only way...