# Is there a GeoJSON load event on Google Maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geojson

I'm currently working on a map using GeoJSON to load countries borders and infos, as well as some in-house data which are supposed to get attached to those countries. The data is in two data layers loaded via the following code :

```
Data[MapType] = new google.maps.Data();
Data[MapType].loadGeoJson(jsonPath, {idPropertyName:geoJSONID});
Data[MapType].setStyle(dataStyle);
Data[MapType].setMap(Map);
```

It works fine, the data is loading, mouseover event handlers are responding well. However I want to hide a loader overlay when the geoJSON file is finished loading and displaying, but so far I haven't found a way to listen to that kind of event.

I saw on [another stackoverflow thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/11257/is-there-an-event-fired-when-a-kml-layer-has-finished-loading-in-google-maps) something for KML about listening to the `metadata_changed` event, but it doesn't trigger anything on my map. The API reference is not much help either.

Do any of you know of a way to know when the geoJSON data is finished loading and displaying ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

there's an `idle` state of the map object, should be able to access it like:

```
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function() {
    console.log('loaded');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9850444/handle-when-drawing-of-polygons-is-complete-in-google-maps-api-v3) expands on datafunk's answer with a workaround to make use of the idle state. (would have added as comment but for link)